# MPI_Cart_shift for top_left or top_right neighbours

Tags: mpi

Using `MPI_Cart_shift` I will successfully get right, left, top and bottom neighbours (in 2D, for example). But If I want to know the neighbours, like `top_left` and `top_bottom`, how would I use `MPI_Cart_shift`?

As I know it only works by providing direction and displacement as parameters in `MPI_Cart_shift`. But for corner neighbours, you have displacements in two directions.

Comment: You probably want `mpi_cart_rank` which supports conversion between arbitrary coordinates in a cartesian topology and process rank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would agree with High Performance Mark. I can also think of two ways:

(1) Find the cartesian coordinates for the current rank (i.e. for each process), then say for e.g. for finding the upper left diagonal neighbour you would need to subtract one each from the coordinates. Then transform these coordinates to a rank. If `-1` is returned (in MPICH/IntelMPI) or `-2` is returned (in OpenMPI) then the process is `MPI_PROC_NULL`, else it is a valid process.

(2) Use `MPI_Cart_shift()` in first dimension to find upper and lower neighbour (say `UP` and `DOWN`). Then shift in second dimension and find left and right neighbours of `UP` and `DOWN`. *These* left and right neighbours are the *diagonal* neighbours of the original process.

Hope that helps.